# Using over partition by to find total monthly sales per machine

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use the partition by roll over method to show total sales by month for each machine but I want the rolling over method to stop and start over whenever the month ends and a new one starts. I was wondering if anyone could give some advice or direction to led me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT v1.[Device ID], v1.Machine, CONVERT(date, V1.[Prcd Date]) as Date, v2.LineTotal,
    SUM(v2.LineTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY v1.Machine ORDER BY v1.Machine, v1.[Prcd Date]) as RollingTotalSales
FROM vending_machine_sales v1
JOIN vending_machine_sales v2
    ON v1.Machine = v2.Machine
    and v1.[Prcd Date] = v2.[Prcd Date]
--WHERE V1.[Device ID] ='VJ300205292'
ORDER BY 2,3;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results (as formatted text - ideally DDL+DML for your sample data).

Comment: You're looking for a *gaps & islands* solution. Sample data would help your question.

Comment: Dale k. thank you for responding so soon, would you like the data itself ? how can i give you sample data?

Comment: Take a look at some other questions in the SQL Server tag, obviously we don't want your real data, we want a [mre] i.e. the minimum necessary to demonstrate the issue you are facing. And this data can be provided as formatted tabular data (again there are guides on how to do that), but if you take the time to create your sample data as DDL+DML (create table + insert into table) you will get responses much faster because people can copy and paste it out to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this (more simple than a gaps and islands approach) is simply to modify your existing query with a slight tweak.

At the moment, you have your SUM with `PARTITION BY v1.Machine` which will calculate the running total for the machine.

However, if you want to split it into months as well (and start a new SUM every month) you can adjust the PARTITION BY to also include the month e.g.,

```
SUM(v2.LineTotal) OVER 
    (PARTITION BY v1.Machine, YEAR(v1.[Prcd Date]), MONTH(v1.[Prcd Date]) -- Added year/month
    ORDER BY v1.Machine, v1.[Prcd Date]) as RollingTotalSales
```

Note if you don't have any sales for the month, you won't get a row in this.

Comment: This worked perfectly, now i can stop pulling my hair out lol thank you so much!!